How to integrate this integration very similar to the Fresnel integral?
Thank you for reading my question!
I want this integral
$$
\int_0^x\sin{(\alpha+t^2)}dt
$$
I know the Fresnel integral is
$$
S(x)=\int_0^x\sin{(t^2)}dt\\
C(x)=\int_0^x\cos{(t^2)}dt
$$
And we can decompose the integration above as
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_0&^x\sin{\alpha}\cos{t^2}+\cos{\alpha}\sin{t^2}dt\\
=&\sin{\alpha}C(x)+\cos{\alpha}S(x)
\end{align*}
$$
But I don't want this form. My problem is to get the original integration in one term instead of two.
Could you give me any advice? Any help is appreciated.
Thank you for your precious time!

Well there is probably no alternative to the result you've found.

The usual "trick" would differentiate twice with respect to $\alpha$, but you will end up with the same result.

Thank you zwim and Abezhiko. I get it now,
